# Conditional vlookup in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a table where the first column is name, and second column is value. The value can either be a 0 or one of pass/fail. I also have time stamps so names can repeat. For example,

```
Column1      Column2      Column3
X            0            12AM
X            Pass         3AM
```

I am trying to do a vlookup to get the pass/fail status. But since I do not know if the 0 will come first or after (and I cannot control the sorting of the lookup table); I need to write a formula that would automatically do a conditional and pick the pass/fail but not the 0. Also - I can't lookup on the time as it changes every x minutes and not available on the main table.

Any clues?

---

I know there are ways to pick the nth item from a vlookup; however, I can't figure out how to get this scenario as the pass/fail won't always be the second one, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think you actually want to use =INDEX with =MATCH() as an array formula here.

I added to your fake data:

```
A       B       C
Panda   0       12AM
Panda   pass    3AM
Panda   0       5AM
Koala   fail    2AM
Koala   0       1PM
Koala   0       3PM
Polar   0       12AM
Polar   pass    9AM
```

You'll get this:

```
E       F
Panda   pass
Koala   fail
Polar   pass
```

In column F where the results are, place this formula and hold down [control] and [shift] and hit [enter]. It won't work if you just hit [enter].

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(E2&"pass",$A$2:$A$9&$B$2:$B$9,0)),INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(E2&"fail",$A$2:$A$9&$B$2:$B$9,0)))
```